# Conditionally delay the loading of server component(s) in Nextjs v13 based on completed async callback(s) in client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm using Nextjs v13 and use a layout.tsx file to render my pages:

```
  ...
  <AuthContextProvider>
  <Protected>
    {children}
  </Protected>
  </AuthContextProvider>
  ...
```

AuthContextProvider is a client side component.
Protected is a server side component, and the child component that gets passed in (a Nextjs page) is a server component.

I'm trying to conditionally render the server components only after the client component has fully loaded based on the completion of a few async calls.

From the Nextjs docs, server components load first, which is occurring. I'm trying to find a way to delay the server components as I need the values of cookies that get set from async calls in my client component. Is there any way to do this in Nextjs 13?

I was thinking maybe I could lazy import, but if I import from a client component, the server component becomes a client component so I'm at a loss for how to accomplish what I'm trying to do.